# Converting from YUV(UYVY) to RGB using imagemagick

Tags: image, imagemagick

I have YUV images. In windows7, `yuvplayer` can open them, as UYVY format.

And I want to convert one of those images to RGB, in Linux environment.

I think I can do conversion using `imagemagick`. But below errors occur.

1) without `-depth 8`

```
$ convert -verbose -size 736x480 yuv:frame-99.yuv frame-99.bmp
yuv:frame-99.yuv=>frame-99.yuv YUV 736x480 736x480+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 707KB 0.040u 0:00.050
yuv:frame-99.yuv=>frame-99.bmp YUV 736x480 736x480+0+0 16-bit DirectClass 1.057MB 0.360u 0:00.129
convert.im6: unexpected end-of-file `frame-99.yuv': No such file or directory @ error/yuv.c/ReadYUVImage/440.
```

2) with -depth 8

```
$ convert -verbose -size 736x480 -depth 8 yuv:frame-99.yuv frame-99.bmp
yuv:frame-99.yuv=>frame-99.yuv[0] YUV 736x480 736x480+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 707KB 0.060u 0:00.070
yuv:frame-99.yuv=>frame-99.yuv[1] YUV 736x480 736x480+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 707KB 0.020u 0:00.039
yuv:frame-99.yuv=>frame-99-0.bmp[0] YUV 736x480 736x480+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 1.057MB 0.670u 0:00.240
yuv:frame-99.yuv=>frame-99-1.bmp[1] YUV 736x480 736x480+0+0 8-bit DirectClass 1.057MB 0.870u 0:00.280
convert.im6: unexpected end-of-file `frame-99.yuv': No such file or directory @ error/yuv.c/ReadYUVImage/440.
```

Size of this file is 706560 bytes.

How can I convert a image?

Comment: Try adding `-depth 8`. It looks like you are using 16-bits at a time and running out of data.

Comment: If that doesn't work, please show filesize in bytes.

Comment: @MarkSetchell filesize is 706560 bytes.

Comment: Try `convert ... UYVY:frame-99.yuv ...` or `convert -sampling-factor 4:2:2 ... UYVY:frame-99.yuv ...`

Comment: You have 16 bits per pixel, whereas YUV has 12, see https://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php Else provide specification of the device that acquired the data and its acquisition mode please.

Comment: Maybe you can show the settings you used successfully with `yuvplayer` http://www.sunrayimage.com/images/YUVFormat_wrong.jpg

Comment: `convert ... UYVY:frame99.yuv` seems working successfully. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried using below command, as Mark Setchell said in comment.

`convert -verbose -size 736x480 UYVY:frame-99.yuv frame-99.bmp`

And I found this works well.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the size you're specifying is too large. Imagemagick tries to fill the space with the data you supply, but encounters the EOF before it's done.
Make sure the `-size` parameter reflects the dimensions of the image you want to convert.

eg:

```
convert rose: UYVY:rose.uyv
convert -size 70x46 -depth 8 UYVY:rose.uyv -colorspace sRGB rose2.png
```