# How to convert raw YUV image to jpg

Tags: linux, image, camera, type-conversion, yuv

I have a raw image that was taken with `v4l2-ctl` after the camera had been setup like:

```
# media-ctl -d /dev/media0 -l "'rzg2l_csi2 10830400.csi2':1 -> 'CRU output':0 [1]"
# media-ctl -d /dev/media0 -V "'rzg2l_csi2 10830400.csi2':1 [fmt:UYVY8_2X8/1280x960 field:none]"
# media-ctl -d /dev/media0 -V "'ov5645 0-003c':0 [fmt:UYVY8_2X8/1280x960 field:none]"
```

and then the picture got snapped with:

```
# v4l2-ctl --device /dev/video0 --stream-mmap --stream-to=frame.raw --stream-count=1
```

now I've tried multiple methods to convert this into a jpeg but nothing seems to yield the expected output

the raw file can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VqXnrJDYbzdtSsWfTlm2mX9rl1-Rl_7F/view?usp=sharing

I tried out the following command:

```
convert -verbose -size 1280x960 UYVY:frame.raw frame.bmp
```

which I found on [Converting from YUV(UYVY) to RGB using imagemagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50793572/converting-from-yuvuyvy-to-rgb-using-imagemagick/50848842)

but it doesn't do the trick

Comment: Maybe you could share the raw file via Google Drive or Dropbox or similar.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I did add a link to the post above.

Comment: It's late here now so I'll take a look tomorrow if no-one else has helped by then.

Comment: Thank you @MarkSetchell , I will do more research myself too! I'm looking forward to getting your response tomorrow then, have a good evening & night!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your frame is 2457600 bytes and your pixel dimensions are 1280x960, so you have:

```
bits per pixel = 2457600 * 8 / (1280 * 960) = 16
```

You can get a list of the pixel formats that `ffmpeg` supports using:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts 2> /dev/null
```

**Sample Output**

```
FLAGS NAME            NB_COMPONENTS BITS_PER_PIXEL
-----
IO... yuv420p                3            12
IO... yuyv422                3            16
IO... rgb24                  3            24
IO... bgr24                  3            24
IO... yuv422p                3            16
IO... yuv444p                3            24
IO... yuv410p                3             9
...
...
```

That means you can get a list of pixel formats that contain `Y`, `U` and `V` with 16 bits per pixel like this:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts 2> /dev/null | awk '/y/ && /u/ && /16$/ {print}'  

IO... yuyv422                3            16
IO... yuv422p                3            16
IO... yuvj422p               3            16
IO... uyvy422                3            16
IO... yuv440p                3            16
IO... yuvj440p               3            16
IO... yvyu422                3            16
```

Now you can run a loop, iterating over all the 16-bit per pixel YUV formats and see what `ffmpeg` makes of your image - naming each result after the format so you can identify which is which:

```
ffmpeg -pix_fmts 2> /dev/null | 
   awk '/y/ && /u/ && /16$/ {print $2}' | 
      while read f; do 
         ffmpeg -y -s:v 1280x960 -pix_fmt $f -i frame.raw $f.jpg
      done
```

That gives you these files:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  304916  3 Feb 09:38 yuv440p.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff  227123  3 Feb 09:38 yuvj422p.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff   39543  3 Feb 09:38 yuyv422.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 mark  staff   39545  3 Feb 09:38 yvyu422.jpg
```

And I guess that `yuyv422.jpg` is your image, so that means you can extract it with:

```
ffmpeg -y -s:v 1280x960 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i frame.raw result.jpg
```

[image]

---

If you wanted to do that with **ImageMagick**, you could do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

python3 <<EOF
import numpy as np
h, w = 960, 1280

# Load raw file into Numpy array
raw = np.fromfile('frame.raw', np.uint8)
raw[0::2].tofile('Y')     # Starting at the 1st byte, write every 2nd byte to file "Y"
raw[1::4].tofile('U')     # Starting at the 2nd byte, write every 4th byte to file "U"
raw[3::4].tofile('V')     # Starting at the 3rd byte, write every 4th byte to file "V"
EOF

# Load the Y channel, then the U and V channels forcibly resizing them, then combine and go to sRGB
magick -depth 8 -size 1280x960 gray:Y \
  \( -size 640x960 gray:U gray:V -resize 1280x960\! \) \
  -set colorspace YUV -combine -colorspace sRGB result.jpg
```

---

If yo don't like/have Python, that part can be replaced with some basic C as follows:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

// Split YUYV file called "frame.raw" into separate channels with filenames "Y", "U" and "V"
// Compile with: clang -O3 splitter.c -o splitter

int main(){

   FILE    *in, *Y, *U, *V;
   uint8_t buffer[4];
   size_t  bytesRead;

   // Open input file and 1 output file per channel
   in = fopen("frame.raw", "rb");   
   Y  = fopen("Y", "wb");   
   U  = fopen("U", "wb");   
   V  = fopen("V", "wb");   

   // read up to sizeof(buffer) bytes
   while ((bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, sizeof(buffer), in)) > 0)
   {
      fputc(buffer[0], Y);
      fputc(buffer[1], U);
      fputc(buffer[2], Y);
      fputc(buffer[3], V);
   }
}
```

---

Having had so much fun doing `ffmpeg`, **Python**, and `C` versions, I thought I'd try just doing it in the shell - converting bytes to lines and so I could pick alternate lines instead of alternate bytes. This works the same as the above:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Build JPEG image from YUYV image with packed bytes in order YUYVYUYV...
# Use "xxd" to convert bytes into lines, then extract alternate lines - which is easier than extracting bytes

H=960
W=1280
INPUT="frame.raw"

# Take top byte of every uint16 and put into "Y.pgm"
xxd -c1 -p "$INPUT" | sed -n 'p;n' | xxd -r -p | magick -size ${W}x${H} -depth 8 gray:- Y.pgm

# Take bottom byte of every 2nd uint16, starting at the 1st, resize up to full width and put into "U.pgm"
xxd -c1 -p "$INPUT" | sed -n 'n;p' | sed -n 'p;n' | xxd -r -p | magick -size $((W/2))x${H} -depth 8 gray:- -resize ${W}x${H}\! U.pgm

# Take bottom byte of every 2nd uint16, starting at the 2nd, resize up to full width and put into "V.pgm"
xxd -c1 -p "$INPUT" | sed -n 'n;p' | sed -n 'n;p' | xxd -r -p | magick -size $((W/2))x${H} -depth 8 gray:- -resize ${W}x${H}\! V.pgm

# Load the 3 channels, combine and convert to JPEG
magick {Y,U,V}.pgm -set colorspace YUV -combine -colorspace sRGB result.jpg

# Remove litter
rm {Y,U,V}.pgm
```

---

As regards colour cast removal, as I said in the comments, the *" normal"* way, AFAIK, is to get the average colour of the image and invert its Hue then blend that *"negated cast"* back with the original image to offset the original colour cast. Here is a crude attempt - if anyone knows better please ping me!

Step 1: Get average colour cast

```
magick result.jpg -resize 1x1\! cast.png
```

[image]

Step 2: Invert the cast

```
magick cast.png -modulate 100,100,0 correction.png
```

[image]

Step 3: Blend the original with the correction and brighten maybe

```
magick result.jpg correction.png -define compose:args=50,50 -compose blend -composite -auto-level result.jpg
```

Here are the original and corrected versions:

[image]

Obviously you can change the percentages for different degrees of *"correction"*.

Comment: the version utilizing ImageMagick however seems to work fine as expected!

Comment: The `ffmpeg` one should actually work - despite giving an error message.

Comment: True, it does work. My apologies, I added the loop into s script and that doesn't work, it gives me: **No such pixel format: uvj440p.
frame.raw: Invalid argument** but the selected command by itself: `ffmpeg -y -s:v 1280x960 -pix_fmt yuyv422 -i frame.raw result.jpg` works fine! Thanks very much for your help!

Comment: Cool - my pleasure. Good luck with your project!

Comment: you know how the picture gets that Yellow tint after the conversion from yuyv422, do you know about a way to get the real colors without getting that yellow tint?

Comment: The *"normal"* way is to get the average colour of the image, invert the hue and blend that back with the original to offset the colour cast. I would suggest you ask a new question to see if any of the rather knowledgeable folk on here have a better idea. Be sure to frame it as a programming question not a Photoshop question else it will get closed. Your image is actually also rather under-exposed which probably isn't helping either. Tag a new question as `image-processing`.